# How to start editing and focusing a row with an onClick event in DataGrid

Tags: reactjs, material-ui

I am using MUI's `DataGrid` and I want to open a specific row editability and focus on it.
I am using the community version of `DataGrid`, is there any way to do it? or only in the data-grid-x version?

Comment: So you want single click instead of double click?

Comment: I want to open it with a button

Answer (score 2):

According to the [docs](https://mui.com/components/data-grid/editing/#start-editing), `DataGrid` switches to editing mode if the following interactions happen:

> - A Enter keydown
> - A Backspace or Delete keydown. It will also delete the
>   value and stops the edit mode instantly.
> - A keydown of any printable key, for instance a, E, 0, or $ A double click on the cell A call to
> - `apiRef.current.setCellMode(id, field, 'edit')`.

If you're using `row` editing, the [conditions](https://mui.com/components/data-grid/editing/#start-editing-2) are a bit different:

> - A Escape keydown. It will also roll back changes done in the row.
> - A Enter keydown. It will also save and goes to the cell at the next row at the same column.
> - A mouse click outside the row
> - A call to apiRef.current.setRowMode(id, 'view').

The only way to go to the editing mode programmatically is to use the imperative API `setCellMode` which is a premium feature unfortunately. The example below shows you how to start editing when the user clicks a cell (`DataGridPro` only):

```
const apiRef = useGridApiRef();
const [editMode, setEditMode] = React.useState<GridEditMode>('cell');
const [editingCell, setEditingCell] = React.useState();

return (
  <div style={{ width: '100%' }}>
    <div style={{ height: 400, width: '100%' }}>
      <Button
        onClick={() => setEditMode((m) => (m === 'cell' ? 'row' : 'cell'))}
      >
        edit mode: {editMode}
      </Button>
      <DataGridPro
        apiRef={apiRef}
        rows={rows}
        columns={columns}
        editMode={editMode}
        onCellClick={({ id, field }) => {
          setEditingCell({ id, field });

          if (editingCell) {
            apiRef.current.setCellMode(editingCell.id, editingCell.field, 'view');
          }
          apiRef.current.setCellMode(id, field, 'edit');
        }}
        onSelectionModelChange={(ids) => {
          if (editMode === 'row') apiRef.current.setRowMode(ids[0], 'edit');
        }}
      />
    </div>
  </div>
);
```

### Live Demo

[image: Codesandbox Demo]

Comment: How to hide "__HIDDEN__" column?