# Can I edit MUI X Data Grid cell without doubleclick?

Tags: reactjs, material-ui, datagrid, mui-x-data-grid

I would like to edit a MUI XData Grid cell, but not by doubleclick. It would be better if the cells always displays as edit mode, or by hover.
Is it possible?

Comment: [Related question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/70003754/9449426)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

mui datagrid editable without double click
https://codesandbox.io/s/material-demo-forked-9zq44?file=/demo.tsx

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).